# GraphViz and the "Unflatten" Tool Layout my Graph Awkwardly

Tags: graphviz

So I'm using Graphviz to generate rather complex graphs. To avoid making them too wide, I'm using the "unflatten" tool which is included with the program to stagger the nodes a bit. However, unflatten lays out the nodes in rather awkward ways out times. For reference, here is my DOT file I'm starting out with:

```
digraph G {
    overlap=scalexy;
    graph [fontname = "Consolas",layout=dot];
    edge  [fontname = "Consolas",fontsize=11];
    node  [fontname = "Consolas", fontsize=11, style=filled, colorscheme=set39];

    Senses -> Sight;
    Senses -> Hearing;
    Senses -> Touch;
    Senses -> Taste;
    Senses -> Smell;
}
```

When I run this code through the unflatten tool, I get this:

```
digraph G {
    graph [fontname=Consolas,
        layout=dot,
        overlap=scalexy
    ];
    node [colorscheme=set39,
        fontname=Consolas,
        fontsize=11,
        style=filled
    ];
    edge [fontname=Consolas,
        fontsize=11
    ];
    Senses -> Sight   [minlen=1];
    Senses -> Hearing [minlen=2];
    Senses -> Touch   [minlen=3];
    Senses -> Taste   [minlen=1];
    Senses -> Smell   [minlen=2];
}
```

[Which looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYKXi.png)

However, modifying this code slightly, like so

```
digraph G {
    graph [fontname=Consolas,
        layout=dot,
        overlap=scalexy
    ];
    node [colorscheme=set39,
        fontname=Consolas,
        fontsize=11,
        style=filled
    ];
    edge [fontname=Consolas,
        fontsize=11
    ];
    Senses -> Sight   [minlen=1];
    Senses -> Hearing [minlen=2];
    Senses -> Touch   [minlen=3];
    Senses -> Taste   [minlen=2];
    Senses -> Smell   [minlen=1];
}
```

[gives me this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfkkZ.png), which is much more like what I want. Now, for such a small graph, the cost of editing the output is trivial. However, this is simply an example, the actual graphs I'm working with are much large, and doing this manually would be impractical. Is there any solution to this problem, or am I out of luck?

Comment: That one looks better than the other is, literally, a matter of `Taste`. I guess you could find out the reason why Taste is assigned that min-len. Is it because of the original order?